# Observable Dictionary and updating bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid, .net-4.5

I've started using WPF recently and I have two problems with bindings..

I'm using this [ObservableDictionary](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/).
When i bind it to TextBox it works flawlessly but i have a problem with DataGrid:

My Button Bindings:

```
Text="{Binding AdiDictionary[AssetName], Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

My DataGrid Bindings:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Name="AdiDataGrid" Background="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AdiDictionary, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Meta-Data Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Key}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Meta-Data Attribute" Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="1*"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my understanding it works like this because ObservableDictionary.Value doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, however I tried multiple solutions and i cannot make it work:(

Second thing: User should have a possibility of loading settings file.

```
void LoadAdiSettingsFileExecute()
{
  var loadDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

  loadDialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";
  loadDialog.Filter = "Txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";

  if ((bool) loadDialog.ShowDialog())
  {
    var textFile = AdiSettingsFile.ReadingSettingsFileToDictionary(loadDialog.FileName);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> x in textFile)
    {
      AdiDictionary[x.Key] = x.Value;
    }
    RaisePropertyChanged("AdiDictionary");
  }
}

bool CanLoadAdiSettingsFileExecute()
{
  return true;
}

public ICommand LoadAdiSettingsFile {get {return new RelayCommand(LoadAdiSettingsFileExecute, CanLoadAdiSettingsFileExecute);}}
```

Unfortunately, while it works - when I debug to see AdiDictionary values they are all there, however it doesn't update any of the TextBoxes or DataGrid:(

Any help will be much appreciated:)

EDIT: Oh and one thing  i forgot to add - when i tried loading file in constructor it worked in textbox and datagrid, so it's probably problem with Bindings.

EDIT 2:
Ok, so probably noob mistake - I didn't know that every TabItem is creating new instance of my ViewModel, and ViewModel constructor is creating new instance of my ObservableDictionary. So i changed it to something like this:

```
private static ObservableDictionary<string, string> _adiDictionary = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

And IT WORKS! However it's slow as hell.. When i change one value of dictionary i have to wait ~7 seconds for it to process everything.  When i load a file that changes about 20 values of that dictionary i have to wait around a minute for it to process it. Do you know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ObservableDictionary.Value should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and then all will work magically.

This is code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MyDictionary<string, string> Dic
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Dic = new MyDictionary<string, string>();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dic["0"] = new Random().Next().ToString();
    }
}

public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TValue this[TKey index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base[index];
        }

        set
        {
            base[index] = value;
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Binding.IndexerName));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This is what I have in my XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Dic[0], Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Content="click me" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Its easy to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in a class. Just fire the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Coul you explain some more? I've tried doing something like this:         public TValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get { return (TValue)_keyedEntryCollection[key].Value; }
            set
            {
                DoSetEntry(key, value);
                OnPropertyChanged(Binding.IndexerName);
            }
        } however it stil doesn't work:/

Comment: I dont know what you doing there but I gave you an example in my answer. Read it carefully.

Comment: What is slow as hell? You have to give me more information what is slow and what are you trying to do exactly? You showed us in your code from above that you are using a DataGrid but now all of a sudden you are talking about TabItems. I dont know what ObservableDictionary is and I havent downloaded that code. I provided your with my code. My code example is not slow to me. As you can see in my example I just created a class that derivates from original Dictionary and when setting value I trigger PropertyChanged. Tell us exactly what you doing or upload your complete code on github.com.

Comment: I think it is not working in the case of initialization `this.Dic = new MyDictionary<string, string>(){ {"1", "First"} };` anything to add to notify during initialization ? [ObservableDictionary.cs](https://gist.github.com/kzu/cfe3cb6e4fe3efea6d24)

Answer (score 0):

I think your binding source is in ths calss AdiDictionary not itself so 
this code   RaisePropertyChanged("AdiDictionary") will not notify your binding  to update the 
TextProperty as your except